# Python Best way to unpacking the sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have csv file with 15 columns. Given the following code, What is the best pythonic way to archieve this?

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for lname, fname, age, phone, email, company, company_no, blah, blah in csv.reader(f):
        pass
```

I was trying to unpacking the sequences but with 15 columns it looks ugly. And I tried like this:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        fname = row[0]
        lname = row[1]
        ...
```

But it's not what i want. How can i archieve this clean?

Comment: You can use `pandas.DataFrame` here. Create a data frame and perform operations over that data frame.

Comment: I heard about that but I was wonder to make it without using thirds

Comment: What do you mean, in **objective** terms, by "clean" and "ugly" here? Stack Overflow is for questions that can be *objectively* answered. Questions asking for best practices, or even language-specific idiomatic suggestions, are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DictReader and access fields by name (possibly providing the names as input to the dictreader constructor).

Unpacking is great for a limited number of fields, but here I would say you have too many fields for things to be sensible, as you say.